# Making MySQL client program thread safe?

Tags: mysql, c, multithreading, thread-safety, d

I'm running into an interesting threadding problem while running a D programming that uses the MySQL C API. I am getting error 2013 "Lost connection to MySQL server during query." The problem appears to occurs when enough threads flood the network interface buffer, but the server still has more to transfer. This is my best guess based on some research and running the program on two different computers. One computer has a 100Mb connection to the server and the other has a 1Gb connection. The computer with the 100Mb connection throws the error, while the 1Gb computer does not. I am wondering if I am running into what is described in the first paragraph of [How to Write a Threaded Client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/threaded-clients.html) in the MySQL documentation. If I am, what do I need to do with SIGPIPE and how do I do it?

For those who are interested, I am calling mysql_library_init before any library call and I am creating a new MYSQL* for each thread with mysql_init and mysql_real_connect. Also of note, the queries that I am executing are small SELECTs, only a few thousand records returned from each query and all queries are executed from the same table.

Comment: Can you post a 20-line program that reproduces the problem?

Comment: you need to throttle the connection, you can use a semaphore to limit the amount of concurrent connections

Comment: How many simultaneous connections to the mysqld are you attempting to establish?  How many connections will your mysqld accept?  If you're going to get this to work robustly, you need to test your threaded C software against a mysqld server with a relatively small number of connections; you will need a connection pool. Also, don't forget to free up your result sets and other C API objects when you're done with them: your mysqld may run out of resources long before your C program does in case of leaks.

Comment: I've been using a thread pool of between 2 and 7.

Comment: The server that I am connecting to allows for more than 64 connections. It has 12 physical cores and more than 100GB of RAM allocated to mysqld.
Ollie, thank you for reminder. I am executing a mysql_free_result when I am done with each set.

Comment: Including all of the mysql function calls, the program would be over 50 lines in its smallest form.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this before mysql_real_connect:

```
my_bool myb = 1;
mysql_options(conn, mysql_option.MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &myb);
```

Also please check this mysql troubleshooting page:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am enabling reconnect before calling mysql_real_connect like you suggested.

I've read through that page several times and read it again just in case I missed something.